# Big stack of Activities on Android causes OutOfMemory

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, out-of-memory

In my app, the user has the possibility to open several activities where each one contains a list of images (RecyclerView) which are loaded using the Glide lib.

The problem is that the more activities the user opens (the greater the activities stack is), the more memory the app consumes.

I have looked everywhere on StackOverflow for a solution to this problem, but I could not find. I cannot simply kill the last activity before starting the new one.

As a good example of how I want my app to work (without lags/OOM), take Google's Play Store App. Through their app, you can open a large number of Activities and without lagging/crashing. And when the user presses the back button, he is returned to the exact scroll position where he was at the last screen.

Comment: Just want to make it clear, how can you open a large amount of Activities from Google's Play Store?

Comment: It's hard to say, we don't know how you load the images. How do you load the images? Are you using a library? Which one? Maybe you can release resources in `onStop` and `onTrimMemory`.

Comment: @CaoMinhVu, by navigating through their content. You can do it endlessly.

Comment: @EugenPechanec, I am using Glide to load the images :)

Comment: @AugustoCarmo, I do not think they keep the old content when you click on a new one. You can check from the back stack (rectangle button), there is only one Activity there, no matter how many applications (content), you browse to

Comment: You can achieve the same thing as them by startActivity with Clear Top flag.
i.e Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Comment: @CaoMinhVu, the problem with these flags is that they gonna mess with the user's  navigation.

Comment: Better to explicitly `finish()` previous activity after launching new one

Comment: @AntonMalyshev, not the ideal solution either. Its gonna mess with the user's back navigation.

Comment: Just process `onBackPressed` manually

Comment: Just checked the log, I think they use a webview and just update the page content. I found no activity switching but the log:
com.google.android.finsky.activities.ba.ci_(27): Page [class=bg] loaded in [75 ms] (hasDetailsDataLoaded? false)